# How to alter code to make it so that when a number less than or equal to zero is input it indicates the end and stops user from inputting data

Tags: matlab

I need to make a number sorter in matlab, which can read integers from user input until a number equal to or less than zero is input. Once a number equal to or less than zero is input the program sorts the numbers in ascending order. I have no idea what to do from here:

```
sortorder = input('Enter the word "up" if you want to sort array in ascending order, \nor enter the word "down" if you want to sort the array in descending order: ', 's');
nvals = input('Enter number of values to sort: ');
switch sortorder
case {'up', 'Up'}
array = zeros(1,nvals);
for ii = 1:nvals
string = ['Enter value ' int2str(ii) ': '];
array(ii) = input(string);
end
sorted = ssort(array);
fprintf('\nSorted date:\n');
for ii = 1:nvals
fprintf(' %8.4f\n',sorted(ii));
end
case {'down', 'Down'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A break statement can be added to the loop reading the input values. Before breaking out of the loop the array can be truncated to delete the extra values that were not filled due to the premature end of inputs (given that a number less than 0 was entered). If you wish not to include the terminating number entered you can truncate the array by changing the line `Array = Array(1,1:Value_Index)` to `Array = Array(1,1:Value_Index-1)`.

```
Sorting_Pattern = input('Enter the word "up" if you want to sort array in ascending order, \nor enter the word "down" if you want to sort the array in descending order: ', 's');
Number_Of_Values = input('Enter number of values to sort: ');
Array = zeros(1,Number_Of_Values);


for Value_Index = 1: +1: Number_Of_Values

 
Input_Value = input(['Enter value ' int2str(Value_Index) ': '],'s'); 
Array(1,Value_Index) = str2num(Input_Value);


if(str2num(Input_Value) <= 0)
%Deleting unused indices in array%
Array = Array(1,1:Value_Index);

%Uncomment to force ascending order upon termination%
% Sorting_Pattern = 'up';

break;
end
    
end


switch Sorting_Pattern
    
    case {'up','Up'}
    Sorted_Array = sort(Array);
    
    case{'down','Down'}
    Sorted_Array = sort(Array,'descend');

end

Sorted_Array
```